# If the random variables $(v_k)$ are i.i.d, are the $(v_k-m_k)$ i.i.d. as well?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

###### This is my first time asking, so if my question is lacking, please let me know so I can edit it.

---

$v_{k}$ is iid across $k$ where $k=1,....K$ and I can represent its CDF as $F(v)$.

(*Note : I have very large $K$ for sure*)

I am creating a *pseudo reservation value* such that $\hat{v}_{k} = v_{k} - \max(0, \max_{k^{'}\neq k}(v_{k^{'}}-c_{k^{'}}))$ where $c_{k^{'}}$ is just constant unique to $k^{'}$.

Let's say $\hat{v}_{k}$ follows new CDF called $\hat{F}(\hat{v_{k}})$.

**Goal**  : I want to show $\hat{F}(\hat{v_k})$ is iid across $k$ ( or at least for majority of $k$)

---

Attempt is the following.
Assume $v_{1}-c_{1} > v_{2}-c_{2} > v_{3}-c_{c} > ... > v_{K}-c_{K}$. Then, we have the follwing.
$$\hat{v}_{1} = v_{1} - \max(0, v_{2}-c_{2}) \quad k=1$$
$$\hat{v}_{k} = v_{k} - \max(0, v_{1}-c_{1}) \quad \text{for } k = 2,...,K$$

**Current Conclusion** :

(1) $Pr(\hat{v}_{k}\leq x) = Pr(v_{k} \leq x+ \max(0, v_{1}-c_{1}))$ for $k=2,...K$. Since I can treat $\max(0, v_{1}-c_{1})$ as some exogenous constant term, and $F(v_{k})$ are identically distributed, $\hat{F}(\hat{v_k})$ is identically distributed for at least $k=2,...,K$.

(2) For sets $A_{2},...,A_{K}$ of possible values of $v_{k}$, $k=2,...,K$,
$$Pr(\hat{v}_{2} \in A_{2} \text{ & } ... \text{ & } \hat{v}_{K} \in A_{K})$$
$$=Pr(v_{k} \in \{ x+\max(0, v_{1}-c_{1}) \quad   x \in A_{k}\}) \text{   for } k= 2,...,K$$
$$ = \Pi_{k=2}^{K} Pr(v_{k} \in \{ x+\max(0, v_{1}-c_{1}) \quad   x \in A_{k}\}))  $$
because $v_{2}, ... v_{K}$ are independent and we have exogenous constant term
$$=Pr(\hat{v}_{2} \in A_{2}) ... Pr(\hat{v}_{K} \in A_{K})$$

**Thus**, can I say that $\hat{F}(\hat{v}_{k})$ is iid for all $k$ except one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't expect the $\mathbf{\hat v}_k$ to be i.i.d. in general.** Here is a simple counterexample :

Let $K=2$ and consider $v_1,v_2\sim\mathrm{Uniform}([1,2])$ i.i.d., then let $c_1 = 3$ and $c_2 = 1$. Because the $v_i$ are almost surely between $1$ and $2$, you have that $\max\{0,v_1-c_1\} = 0$ and $\max\{0,v_2-c_2\} = v_2-c_2$ almost surely. Hence, with your definition, it follows that
$$\hat v_1 = v_1 - (v_2-c_2)\,\text{ and }\, \hat v_2=v_2 $$
You can see that $\hat v_1$ and $\hat v_2$ are not independent, and are not identically distributed either.

Actually, the $\hat v_k$ are defined in such a way that they are very likely to **not** be independent. Indeed, because of term $\max(0, \max_{k^{'}\neq k}(v_{k^{'}}-c_{k^{'}}))$ which appears in all of them, the $\hat v_k$ actually depend on **all** of the $(v_i)_{1\le i \le K}$, meaning that they will correlate with each other most of the time.

With that being said, it is still possible for them to have the same distribution : Denote $m_k:=\max(0, \max_{k{'}\neq k}(v_{k^{'}}-c_{k^{'}}))$. By the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Continuous_case) we have
$$\begin{align}F_{\hat v_k}(x):=\mathbb P(\hat v_k \le x) &= \mathbb P\left(v_{k} - m_k\le x\right)\\
&=\int_{t\in\mathbb R}\mathbb P\left(v_{k} \le x+t\ |\ m_k = t\right)f_{m_k}(t)dt\\
&=\int_{t\in\mathbb R}\mathbb P\left(v_{k} \le x+t\right)f_{m_k}(t)dt\\
&=\int_{t\in\mathbb R}F_{v}( x+t)f_{m_k}(t)dt \end{align} $$
Where $f_{m_k}$ is the density function of $m_k$.

From that calculation, we can see that if the coefficients $c_k$ are chosen such that all the $m_k$ have the same distribution, then the $\hat v_k$ will have the same distribution as well. A simple example of $c_k$ for which that is the case would be to take all the $c_k$ equal to each other.

Comment: Dear @StratosFair, thank you very much for your answer. May I ask some follow up questions? To give background, I am not trying to formally prove my question but rather use it for empirical analysis when K is very big. In this case, is my conclusion to say $v_{k}$ is iid for nearly all k(in my example 2 to K) wrong? Sorry if I am not making any sense in statistical term....

Comment: Glad to help ! Unfortunately, $K$ being large does not change the fact that each $\hat v_k$ is basically a function of **all** the $(v_i)_{1\le i \le k}$, so they will most likely not be independent (except for specific, well-chosen values of the constants $c_k$). Similarly, the fact that they are identically distributed does not depend on $K$ being large either, it boils down to choosing the $c_k$ in a way that makes it true. If you have any more questions that require more context, feel free to create a separate question, the community will be happy to help you !

Comment: Dear @StratosFair, thank you very much for you additional comment. So to check whether I am getting this correctly, let me write down what I understood. $\hat{v}_{k}$ depends on the order of $v_{k}$s, so it is hard to have independence. Similarly, for identically distributed, each $c_{k}$ have to have same distribution for $m_{k}$. In that case, if assume $c_{k}=c$ for all k, this will solve the identically distributed part. Would this also solve independence? I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much

Comment: Yep, what you wrote is right. Regarding setting $c_k=c$ for all $k$, it will make all the $\hat v_k$ identically distributed, but definitely not independent. Getting independence of all of the $\hat v_k$ seems pretty hard, it will depend on the distribution of the $v_k$ and what kind of constraints you have on the coefficients $c_k$.

Comment: Dear @StratosFair, I really appreciate your help. While this is not the result that I wanted to have, I know where the problem lies and where to start the tackle. I hope you have a good day(or night)